# New harddrive does not show up in /dev

Tags: hard-disk, vmware, qnx

I am trying to add a second (unformatted) IDE hard drive to a QNX 6.4.1 VM (hosted through vmware's vSphere). Unfortunately, there is no entry for the drive in `/dev`  (I think this is called an enumeration... is that correct?)

I would have expected an entry named `/dev/hd1` that I could then put a QNX6 filesystem on, partition, and mount. But all I see is `/dev/hd0`.

`devb-eide` is running. I tried moving it from Primary Slave to Secondary Master in the BIOS, but it didn't seem to help.

This has always worked for me on my local VMs before, but now that we are hosted in vSphere, I don't know. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

[image: BIOS screenshot]
[image: /dev screenshot]

Update:
So it looks like QNX calls /dev/hd0 a "Hard Disk Block Device"
  [Link](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/user_guide/files.html)

> /dev/hdn   Hard disk block devices; data representing an entire drive,
>   spanning all partitions; see devb-* in the Utilities Reference.

Is the term "Hard Disk Block Device" standard across many *nix?

Update:
For what it's worth, I also do not get a `/etc/fstab` showing up.